# Popup Lost the Focus on Navigation in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

While using the List View or List Box inside the Popup its behavior looks abnormal on the navigation operation. We have the design as like, loaded the list view inside popup control. On navigate the list view using navigation keys after reaching the last item of the list view, that the actual parent of the popup control starts navigating for my action how to avoid this navigation. In the below code after reaching the List Box last Item the Grid catch the focus and start scrolling.

```
 <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ToggleButton Height="20" Width="20"
                        x:Name="PART_ColorPickerToggleButton"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        IsTabStop="True">
                <ToggleButton.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1">
                            <Rectangle
                                        x:Name="PART_Rectangle"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                        Fill="Orange" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ToggleButton.Template>
            </ToggleButton>
            <Popup Opened="PART_ColorPickerPalettePopup_Opened"
                   Height="100"
                   Closed="PART_ColorPickerPalettePopup_Closed"
                        x:Name="PART_ColorPickerPalettePopup"
                        PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_ColorPickerToggleButton}"
                        Width="250"
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                        AllowsTransparency="False"
                        Focusable="True"
                        HorizontalOffset="1"
                        IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=PART_ColorPickerToggleButton, Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        PopupAnimation="Slide"
                        StaysOpen="False"
                        VerticalOffset="1">
                <ListBox x:Name="list" PreviewKeyDown="list_PreviewKeyDown">
                </ListBox>
            </Popup>
            <CheckBox Content="HI" Grid.Row="1" Height="25"/>
            <CheckBox Content="HI" Grid.Row="2" Height="25"/>
            <CheckBox Content="HI" Grid.Row="3" Height="25"/>
            <CheckBox Content="HI" Grid.Row="4" Height="25"/>
            <CheckBox Content="HI" Grid.Row="5" Height="25"/>
            <CheckBox Content="HI" Grid.Row="6" Height="25"/>
            <CheckBox Content="HI" Grid.Row="7" Height="25"/>
            <CheckBox Content="HI" Grid.Row="8" Height="25"/>
            <CheckBox Content="HI" Grid.Row="9" Height="25"/>
            <CheckBox Content="HI" Grid.Row="10" Height="25"/>
            <CheckBox Content="HI" Grid.Row="11" Height="25"/>
            <CheckBox Content="HI" Grid.Row="12" Height="25"/>
            <CheckBox Content="HI" Grid.Row="13" Height="25"/>
            <CheckBox Content="HI" Grid.Row="14" Height="25"/>
            <CheckBox Content="HI" Grid.Row="15" Height="25"/>
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should apply the attached property [`KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigation.directionalnavigation?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Input.KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation);k(VS.XamlEditor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.8)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) to the `ListBox` and set it to [`KeyboardNavigationMode.Cycle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigationmode?view=netframework-4.8):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" 
         KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
```

Comment: Thanks @BionicCode How to restrict the mouse scroll outside of the popup...see  while the mouse move action captured  by the grid even if the popup is stayed open..is there any property to avoid this.

Comment: I have tested the code. But its not a expected behavior, by this code its looping on the navigation i want to stop the key navigation at last.

Comment: Then just surround the `ListBox` with a `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: That's working while loaded the `ListBox` inside `ScrollViewer.`, How to restrict the mouse wheel action on moving outside the Popup

Comment: There is no build in solution to achieve this. You could track the state of the `Popup` by binding the `IsOpen` property to a property somewhere in the `DataContext` of the `Popup` and the outer `ScrollViewer` (the scroll viewer outside the `Popup`). Then create an Attached Behavior, which you attach to the outer `ScrollViewer`. Now inside this Attached Behavior you intercept the mouse wheel event by subscribing to the observed scroll viewer `ScrollViewer.PreviewMouseWheel` event and set it to handled if the `Popup` is opened.